# Как в android воспроизвести звук одновременно с нескольких приложений?

Tags: android, аудио, root

Каким образом в Android можно воспроизвести звук одновременно в нескольких приложениях? Если же попытаться запустить плеер, когда уже играет какой-то другой, то первый встанет на паузу.
Спасибо

Comment: Первый встаёт на паузу, потому что об  этом позаботился его разработчик - сделал реакцию на потерю аудио-фокуса. Это норма поведения плеера для мобильных устройств. Но ничто не мешает вам забить на правила и не следить за фокусом - тогда ваша поделка будет тарахтеть при любых обстоятельствах (не уверен только насчёт звонков - на время вызова и разговора система может сама гасить лишнее).

Comment: Тогда каким образом я могу забить на потерю аудио фокуса? Мне надо перехватывать вызовы или что?

Comment: Для этого как раз ничего не нужно - запустить воспроизведение и всё.

Comment: Так они ж встают на паузу, если я буду их по очереди включать

Comment: Вы своё писать собираетесь или с чужими играться? Своё как напишете так и будет работать, а если пользоваться чужими - это уже оффтоп и вопрос к их разработчикам, либо туда где модифицируют чужие приложения.

Comment: чужое конечно, я в самом начале это указал

Comment: Тогда оффтоп - этот сайт посвящён проблемам в разработке собственного ПО, а не юзания готового чужого. В двух словах - если плееры не играют одновременно, то без их модификации, либо каких-то ковыряний под рутом вы ничего с этим не поделаете. Есть микроскопический шанс в режиме разделения окна (если аппарат поддерживает) - но очень сильно сомневаюсь. А вообще есть же приложения специально для этого (микширования музыки, наложения разных эффектов и т.д. и т.п.) - просто найдите подходящее и всего делов.

Comment: Так модифирование ос под рутом не является оффтопом тут, а к тому всё и шло. Просто в примере два плеера, может быть больше, нужно именно плееры а музыку микшировать.

Comment: Ну так и опишите в вопросе что вы хотите добиться и какими средствами - сейчас это совсем не очевидно.

Comment: Думал это понятно из вопроса